# Mixed conditionals - Future / Future

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, conditionals, future, sequence-of-tenses

It is the first time that I ask a question, thanks in advance to whoever is going to reply.
I am studying conditional sentences and I cannot find anywhere a structure for a hypotethical future situation with a future result. I am giving you an example to understand if it is possible to express what I want to say, please correct me if I am wrong.

"If I were going to the concert tonight, I would be fulfilling the dream of my life"

Comment: That's fine, no problem at all.

Comment: Hmmm... Do you mean that the condition of  being on your way to the concert would fulfill the dream of your life? Or do you mean that going to and attending the concert would fulfill that dream?

Answer (score 1):

To cast the hypothetical distinctly into the future, employ the future periphrastic subjunctive mood, for example:

"If I were to go to the concert tonight, I would be fulfilling a lifetime dream."

-or-

"If I were going to go to the concert tonight, I would be fulfilling a lifetime dream."

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer Billy. I thought that future conditional sentences should have the following structure: "If+past continuous" but you suggested "If+were going to+verb". So If I want to say "If it rains, I will stay home" in the future stucture, should I say "If it were going to rain, I would be staying home" and "If it were raining, I would be staying home" is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your existing sentence is fine. You can change it if you wish, but there is no reason to do so.

> If I were going to the concert tonight, I would be fulfilling the dream of my life.

This is something you might say the morning of the concert, before it takes place that night.